# Puppet init script doesn't create the pid file?

Tags: bash, puppet, init.d, sysv

- CentOS release 5.4 (Final)
- `puppet-server-2.7.19-1.el5` is installed from the puppetlabs repo.

`puppetmaster` is started successfull, but it doesn't create the pid file. It is the reason for `[ FAILED ]` message when stopping:

```
/etc/init.d/puppetmaster stop
Stopping puppetmaster:                                     [FAILED]
```

The init script: http://fpaste.org/nsfI/

The `/etc/rc.d/init.d/functions` library: http://fpaste.org/ox5Q/

And this is what I get when running in the debug mode: http://fpaste.org/DkoS/

I know the way to `echo` the pid to a file manually after starting, but why doesn't `daemon` function's `--pidfile` work?

`daemon $PUPPETMASTER $PUPPETMASTER_OPTS --masterport=${PUPPETMASTER_PORTS[$i]} --pidfile=/var/run/puppet/puppetmaster.${PUPPETMASTER_PORTS[$i]}.pid`

Sure, Puppet master is running as `puppet` user:

```
ps -ef | grep [p]uppet
puppet   23418     1  0 18:13 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/ruby /usr/sbin/puppetmasterd
```

and the owner of `/var/run/puppet/` folder is `puppet`:

```
# ls -ld /var/run/puppet/
drwxr-xr-x 2 puppet puppet 4096 Sep 17 18:46 /var/run/puppet/
```

Comment: Include the name/version/distro of the OS that you are using. Also post the output of running "which daemon". The problem is likely with the daemon command but I am having trouble tracking down docs/bug listings for same.

Comment: On the Red Hat based, `daemon` is a "standard" function that is defined in the `/etc/rc.d/init.d/functions` script. Updated my question.

Comment: The links to fpaste.org are broken... :(

Answer (score 2):

It is up to the controlled program (in this case `puppetmasterd`), not the `daemon()` function, to create the pidfile; `daemon()` relies on this.

**Confirm** where `puppetmasterd` creates its pidfile (it could be `/var/run/puppet.pid`, `/var/lib/puppet/run/master.pid`, etc.)  To find out, inspect the contents of `puppetmasterd` (if a script), or kill `puppetmasterd` then `strace -f puppetmasterd 2>&1 | grep '\.pid'`.

Modify the value of `pidfile` in your `/etc/init.d/puppetmaster` accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

So, it looks to me like there could be a couple of possibilities here:

1. If you are trying to use the --pidfile option of the daemon command I believe you have a syntax problem.

   - Red Hat's daemon command has the following (unhelpful) signature: `Usage: daemon [+/-nicelevel] {program}`.  **What isn't altogether clear is that anything that you include after the program location is treated as an option passed to the program, not to the daemon function call.**
   - So, in your case you are passing the `--pidfile` argument to `$PUPPETMASTER` itself as opposed to `daemon()`.  You could remedy this by using the following: `daemon --pidfile=/var/run/puppet/puppetmaster.${PUPPETMASTER_PORTS[$i]}.pid $PUPPETMASTER $PUPPETMASTER_OPTS --masterport=${PUPPETMASTER_PORTS[$i]}`
2. The second option here is that `$PUPPETMASTER` (or rather, the program behind it) might daemonize itself, and if so, could be responsible for creating its own .pid file.  The process management tool [Circus](https://circus.readthedocs.org/en/latest/for-ops/configuration/) works in this way.  It's probably an option in a configuration file or for the program representing by `$PUPPETMASTER`.

   - I'm not a Puppet user, so I won't be able to help you with the specifics here.  But I would look into the [Puppet labs documentation](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/) to find out more about this option.
   - It is important to note if $PUPPETMASTER is daemonizing itself, then the `--pidfile` argument being passed to `daemon()` will have no effect.

Good hunting!